# Time dilation calculation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

I saw this example in a book, where it portrays the following situation:

A guy is standing in a train travelling at a speed **V** and the train cart has a height of **h**, and there is a bulb attached to the top of the cart. The individual in the cart sees that the light reaches the ground in $$t_1 = h/c$$
an individual seeing the light from outside the cart sees the light reaching the floor in time:
$$t_2 = \frac{\sqrt{h^2+(vt_1)^2}}{c}$$
If you simplify and replace $$h/c=t_1$$ in the second equation, you get the following:
$$t_2=t_1\sqrt{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
How do you get to the Lorentz factor from this equation?

Comment: Do you know what the Lorentz factor is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traveler-guy says the light hits the ground at time $t_1$.  This is reflected in your first equation.

To get your second equation, you presumably drew a triangle with height $h$ and length $vt_1$.  This means you implicitly assumed that according  to station-guy, the light travels a horizontal distance $vt_1$ before hitting the ground.  But that's wrong --- according to station-guy, the train is traveling at velocity $v$ for $t_2$ seconds, not $t_1$ seconds, before the light hits.  So your triangle should have had a base of $vt_2$, not $vt_1$.

Comment: Ohh my bad... thanks for pointing that out!